# filter array values from a dictionary

Tags: php, arrays

I have an $array on php, and I'd like to know if the values are from a specific dictionary.

For example, if my dictionary is an array of values ['cat', 'dog', 'car', 'man'] I'd like to filter my $array and return false if a word into this one is not on the dictionary.

So, if $array is :

```
['men', 'cat'] // return false;
['man', 'cat'] // return true;
['cat', 'dogs'] // return false;
[''] // return false;
```

and so on...

How can I filter an array in this manner?

Comment: Are you sure your example is correct?

Comment: uhm...yes? why it should be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkDictionary($array,$dictionary){
  foreach($array as $array_item){
    if(!in_array($array_item,$dictionary)){
      return false;
    }
  }
 return true;
}
```

you can also do something like:

```
function checkDictionary($array,$dictionary){
$result =  (empty(array_diff($array,$dictionary))) ? true : false;
 return $result;
}
```

Comment: Note that the first example is something like `O(n*m)` as you potentially loop over all words in the dictionary for all words you search for. I assume `array_diff` is more optimized (somehow)...

Comment: Note to the second example - you can't use `empty` on function returns, you have to assign it to the variable first.

Answer (score 1):

```
function doValuesExist($dictionary, $array) {
    return (count(array_intersect($dictionary,$array)) == count($array));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To increase performance, you should convert you "dictionary" to an associative array, where the keys are the words in the dictionary:

```
$dict = array_flip($dict);
```

Then all you have to do is to loop over the values you search for, which is `O(n)`:

```
function contains($search, $dict) {
    foreach($search as $word) {
        if(!array_key_exists($word, $dict)) {
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

**Reference:** [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php), [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)